Third Time's The Charm
(code 1) = COMMA = PSYCH
APEIRON = (code 2) = FRANKEN
ROSEN EELS = LUSAKA AND = (code 3)
? (5) = (Japanese city) = (TF2 class)
(Tasty) = ? (6) = (Round)
(Rumors) = ? (6) = (Response of affirmation)
(Pastimes) = (Sticker) = ? (5)
(Criminal) = (Bird) = ? (5)
Check your words: Σa1z26 mod 27 = {0,13,14,23,24}
(?) = ERROR: WORD DOES NOT EXIST = ?
? = (?) = ?
? = ? = (?)
Check your words: Σa1z26 mod 27 = {0,2,12}
(?) (?) (?) -> (9)
